# How can I bulk set the value of some results, while limiting how many I update?

Tags: swift, realm

In the code below, I like the simplicity of calling
results.setValue, rather than iterating over an array and calling it a bunch of times.

It seems likely that there is some way to do this without iterating over an array, but I guess really my concern is that it appears to be significantly slower to iterate.  In my testing, for 500 results, it took just under 3 milliseconds to update them in bulk, vs. 537 milliseconds to iterate.

Seems like there has got to be a built in way to set the value for a subset of the results.  Limiting the results by a count doesn't appear to be supported, due to the lazy nature, but I don't see any simple way to update them in bulk.  I could order them by a unique field, and get the 500th and then filter I suppose to get a new result set, but seems like there should be a better way to do it.

```
var results = realm.objects(CloudUpdate.self).filter("status = %@", "queued")
let limitedResults = updates[0..<500]
try! realm.write {
  // this works, except it sets all the results to posted
  // results.setValue("posted", forKey: "status")
  // I'd like to be able to do
  // limitedResults.setValue("posted", forKey: "status")
  // or something rather than iterate as below
  // -- note that limitedResults gets smaller as we set them
  // because of the filter on the results.
  while limitedResults.count > 0 {
    limitedResults[0].setValue("posted", forKey: "status")
  }
}
```

Comment: I added an answer which seems to address the question but I may be able to improve it if it was more clear what the use case is? Why do you need to update the first X number of objects instead of all of them?

Comment: Your answer worked great, I've accepted it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm can do that update using key paths of the object, and the performance over large datasets is very good.

The use case is not clear but if you have a dataset and want to update the first X number of objects, this will do it

Given a person class with a name property

```
class PersonClass: Object {
   @Persisted var name = ""
}
```

and you want to update the first three names to... "Jay"

```
let peopleResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self)    
let peopleList = RealmSwift.List<PersonClass>()
peopleList.append(objectsIn: peopleResults[0...2]) //see note
try! realm.write {
   peopleList.setValue("Jay", forKey: "name")
}
```

Keep in mind though, as soon as realm objects are manipulated by high level Swift functions, the performance will degrade and more importantly, those objects are no longer lazily loaded - they are all loaded into memory and could potentially overwhelm the device.

One other thing to note is that Realm has no pre-defined ordering so ensure the results have a `.sorted(byKeyPath:` if you want to update objects by an order.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer.  I had figured out a slightly different solution, so I forgot to check back in for a bit, my apologies.  In my case, my objects have primary key, so I created a second result query using the keys from the first X objects, and then updated that whole query.  Your solution is a bit more elegant though, thanks :)